# Using AlpineJS (3) magic properties in javascript function

Tags: javascript, alpine.js

I'm using a store for a modal and like to use the magic `$watch` method like so:

```js
Alpine.store('modal', {
    init() {
        this.$watch('this.open', (val) => console.log(val))
        // Here I like to do if(open) { document.body.classList.add('overflow-hidden') } 
    },
    open: false,
    id: null,
    close() {
        this.open = false
        this.id = null
    }
})
```

But I get `TypeError: this.$watch is not a function`

Comment: Is there a specific reason why you are not using Alpine's build in way to bind classes? (https://alpinejs.dev/directives/bind#class-object-syntax)
In this case, you could add `x-data :class="{ 'overflow-hidden': $store.modal.open }"` to your body element.

Comment: Yeah is because I extracted the code into a JS file that I can reuse. And in that JS file I want to watch the `open` value so that I can add a class to the body. I don't want to add an `x-data` on the body.

Comment: Did you find a solution to this?

Comment: No I actually didn't. What you could try is to add a function that you always use to open the modal, like: `open() { this.open = true; document.body.classList.add('overflow-hidden') }`. I never tried this in an external component. Not sure if the `document` object works like this here.

Answer (score 2):

Wrap the second argument in an arrow function:

```js
Alpine.store('modal', () => ({
    init() {
        this.$watch('this.open', (val) => console.log(val))
    },
    open: false,
    id: null,
    close() {
        this.open = false
        this.id = null
    }
}))
```

Arrow functions capture the `this` value of the enclosing context, thus giving you access to Alpine's magic methods.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use the $watch in the Alpine.store, still you have two options available

1. Copying store's data way

Use Store's data as x-data of html element and watch for that data using $watch in html itself. So here `mystore's` data will be the x-data itself so watching it will eventually watch store's `isStoreOpen` property of that store.

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/alpinejs@3.x.x/dist/cdn.min.js"></script>
<script>
 Alpine.store('mystore',{
    init() {
      console.log('hi there in store')

    },
    isStoreOpen: true,
    toggle() {
        
          this.isStoreOpen = !this.isStoreOpen;
    }
 })
</script>

<div x-data="$store.mystore" x-init="$watch('isStoreOpen', (val) => console.log(val))">
  <p>
    What you can toggle
  </p>
  <button @click="toggle()" x-text="$store.mystore.isStoreOpen">
    
  </button>
</div>
```

2. Parameters passing way.

Or for some reason if you need to use magic things in store's method itself or have different `x-data` then you have to pass magic things using parameters. Here i took `startStoreWatch` method in `init` method of data instead of `init` method of store as the store's `init` method is used to init that store.

This way store will watch it's own property same as the data watches it's own.

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/alpinejs@3.x.x/dist/cdn.min.js"></script>
<script>
 Alpine.store('mystore',{
    init() {
      console.log('hi there in store')
            
    },
    count: 0,
    startStoreWatch($watch, $store) {
     $watch('$store.mystore.count', (val) => console.log(val))
    },
    toggle() {
       this.count++;
    }
 })
</script>

<div x-data="{
      init() {
         // here we are watching isOpen of data and count of store
         this.$store.mystore.startStoreWatch(this.$watch, this.$store)
         this.$watch('isOpen', (val) => console.log(val))
      },
      isOpen: false,
      toggle() {
        this.isOpen = !this.isOpen;
      }
}">
  <p x-show="isOpen">
    What you can toggle
  </p>
  <button @click="() => {
    toggle()
    $store.mystore.toggle()
  }" x-text="`store is toggled ${$store.mystore.count} times`">
    
  </button>
</div>
```